# Push to array with v-model

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to **Vue.js**, and I'm trying to create a shop app with **Vue** & **Webpack**. I have some products in a `json` file, and rendering them with a `v-for`.

When clicking on **Add to cart** button, it should put the product number, and the selected quantity to an array.

How can I properly increase quantity for a specific product?
So far I have the following:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(product, index) in products" >
    <div><img :src="product.product_image" /></div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" min="0" v-model="qty[index]" />
      <button @click="addToCart(product.id, qty[index])">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

  import productList from '../products.json';

  export default{
    name: 'shop',
    data(){
      return {
        products: productList,
        cartElements: [],
        qty: [],
      }
    },
    props: [ 'itemsInCart' ],
    methods:{
      addToCart(product_id, quantity){
        this.cartElements.push( {
          "id" : product_id,
          "quantity" : quantity,
        } );
        console.log(this.cartElements);
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

The result is ok, but the input fields are acting weird.

e.g. If I increase the third product's input, it sets the first and second product input to `1`, and only then sets the third input to the desired number.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a Jsfiddle so you can help people understand your problem and get a much faster answer. I can make a lot of well placed guesses why, but I need to test it.

Comment: at first `qty[index]` is not exist, i think you must first in `created` initial `qty` by `productList`!

Comment: I had to do it without webpack, but with simple vue.js it would be something like this:https://jsfiddle.net/vo7y02eg/

Comment: @renataedit But this works correct! what's the wrong?

Comment: The result is ok, but the input fields are acting weird.
E.g.: If I increase the third product's input, it sets the first and second product input to 1, and only then sets the third input to the desired number.

Comment: Initialize  `qty: [null,null,null,null],`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting `qty = []` to be automatically populated by the `v-model` directive. Try initializing that array yourself using vuejs' `created` function, like this:

```vue
<template>
<div v-for="(product, index) in products" >
    <div><img :src="product.product_image" /></div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" min="0" v-model="qty[index]" />
        <button @click="addToCart(product.id, qty[index])">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
    
    
<script>
import productList from '../products.json';
export default{
    name: 'shop',
    data(){
        return {
            products: productList,
            cartElements: [],
            qty: [],
        }
    },
    props: [ 'itemsInCart' ],
    methods:{
        addToCart(product_id, quantity){
            this.cartElements.push( {
                id" : product_id,
                quantity" : quantity,
            });
            console.log(this.cartElements);
        },
    },
    created: function () {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++){
            this.$set(this.qty, i , 0) // This is the vuejs-way of setting array values
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That one worked! :) I had to modify 2 things:
Put "var i = 0;" before the for loop, and changed "this.qty.$set(i, 0)" to "this.$set(this.qty, i, 0)"

Comment: Cool it helped you @renataedit, I modified my answer to reflect your 2 modifications

Answer (score 0):

So with andresgottlieb's help, my final code looks like this:

```
<template>
<div v-for="(product, index) in products" >
    <div><img :src="product.product_image" /></div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" min="0" v-model="qty[index]" />
        <button @click="addToCart(product.id, qty[index])">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import productList from '../products.json';
export default{
    name: 'shop',
    data(){
        return {
            products: productList,
            cartElements: [],
            qty: [],
        }
    },
    props: [ 'itemsInCart' ],
    methods:{
        addToCart(product_id, quantity){
            this.cartElements.push( {
                "id" : product_id,
                "quantity" : quantity,
            } );
            console.log(this.cartElements);
        },
    },
    created() {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++){
            this.$set(this.qty, i, 0) // This is the vuejs-way of setting array values
        }
    }
}
</script>
```